# AngularJS - can you rename a service without modifying its core source?

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I've downloaded a written service for `angular.js`, and it works fine - but I would prefer to have it called something different in my code just for the convenience and readability. It isn't really a requirement, just a desire.

I could go through and change this in the actual source code for the service, but that's obviously going to lead to all kinds of problems. So I was wondering, is this kind of thing possible? Can you 'alias' a service across your application so that it can be referred to something differently when you're passing it through controllers? For example...

## normal

```
var app = angular.module('demo', [ 'ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary' ]);

app.controller('HomeController', function(ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary){
   ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary.open();
});
```

## goal

```
var app = angular.module('demo', [ 'ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary' ]);
var smallerName = ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary;

app.controller('HomeController', function(smallerName){
   smallerName.open();
});
```

I tried just doing that, assigning it to another variable, but it didn't work.

## Update

I actually did make *something* work, but I'm not sure if this will have bad repercussions down the line.

```
var app = angular.module('demo', [ 'ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary' ]);

app.service('ngSmaller', function(ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary) {
   return ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary;
});

app.controller('HomeController', function(ngSmaller){
   ngSmaller.open();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject it like that, this way the services names as strings in array will be resolved to the name of attributes in function, ORDER is important

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary', function(shortName){
   shortName.open();
}]);
```

---edit -----

or with injector

```
var injector = angular.injector(['demo', 'ng']);
var shortName = injector.get('ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary');

app.controller('HomeController', function(shortName){
  shortName.open();
});
```

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to avoid having those long names in every controller. The idea was to do this in one place, and not have to repeat it everywhere.

Comment: I'll extend my answer then

Comment: I added an update to my question, as I just tried this new trick. It actually seems to work, but I'm fearful that there is a lot more going on than I am aware of and it'll backfire horribly.

Comment: Oh, yes. Just change it on the injector. That's perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: The accepted answer doesnt work for me. The injector way of renaming services doesnt seem to be working. Are you sure it works? Check this fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/7t5mc5n4/3/#&togetherjs=iu3Cgr8AfU

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the service with an alias name and then use it everywhere in the application. It will even keep the same one instance even if you use the long name:

```
app.service("shortName", ["ngSomethingLongAndObtuseThatIsNotNecessary", function (originalService) { return originalService; }]);

app.controller("HomeController", ["shortName", function(service) {
   service.open();
}]);
```

Similarly you can alias whole modules:

```
angular.module("shortModuleName", ["veryVeryLoooooooooooooooooooongModuleName"]);
```

Comment: This solution isnt going to work unless you use a factory instead of service.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach can be just create a new factory with a smaller name but use functionality of the existing service. Possibly can help in achieving what you want without polluting the global namespace.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('simpleService',['IHaveAVeryLongOrConfusingName', function(foo){
  return foo;
}])
```