# Conflict between custom Image service and native Image element constructor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, dependency-injection

I am working with a custom Angular service named **Image**. I now realize that this is a terrible name to call one's service, because it conflicts with [Javascript's native Image element constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) also named **Image**.

*So when trying to use both this custom Image service and the native javascript Image element constructor I am running into issues...*

Unfortunately, this service name has been set in stone long before my time developing in this project. Additionally, renaming this Image service to something else is not really an option due to the vast and widespread dependencies through the application that rely on deriving functionality from the name of the **Image** service.

**Is there a good way to get around this conflict?**

I found a work around where I rename the custom Image service during dependency injection:

```
angular.module('app').directive('imageModificationModal', [
  'Image',
  function(MyImage) {
    ...
```

But this seems like really bad practice, plus could cause debugging headaches.

Comment: Check this it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075872/angularjs-can-you-rename-a-service-without-modifying-its-core-source][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most unobtrusive way is to inject it with `$injector` instead of annotation:

```
var ImageService = $injector.get('Image');
```

To avoid name conflicts a service synonym can be defined for use in places where native `Image` and `Image` service are supposed to be used simulataneously.

```
app.config((ImageProvider, $provide) => {
  $provide.provider('ImageService', ImageProvider);
});
```

And/or native `Image` constructor can be injected by a different name:

```
app.constant('NativeImageElementConstructorWhatever', Image);
```